# Ubuntu 18.04 Terminal, Software & Updates, Software Updater not working

Tags: python, versions

I'm new to Linux/Ubuntu. It's been a few days since I was on my computer, but the Terminal, Software & Updates, Software Updater not working when I fired it up. (Ubuntu 18.04)

I have been using this computer mainly to learn about Linux and coding Python using PyCharm as a hobby so the only software on this system, other than "out of the box" Ubuntu 18.04 is Pycharm and Kite as well as some libraries for coding.

I have tried restarting and a hard reboot. In the top right corner an error "A problem has occurred when checking for updates." I can't interact with any of it except toggling "Show notifications". Clicking on "Show updates" or "Preferences" does nothing.

When I try to open the Terminal by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> nothing happens. When I click on the Terminal icon I get a spinning icon for about thirty seconds and it show up in the "Activities" area in the top left, but then crashes with no message.

I have been able to access the Terminal through PyCharm. I deactivated the virtual environment and got to my root directory. From there I tried `sudo apt-get update` and received an error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'python
```

I think what happened is that the last time I was using this computer, I saw some notifications saying I needed to upgrade from python 3.6.9 due to security issues. I was able to upgrade to 3.7.5, but I ran into issues with it using the wrong version as my default. I followed a guide I found online to change it and everything seemed to be working fine. I suspect I somehow either overwrote, uninstalled, or otherwise led my system to overlook Python 2.7--which, as I understand it, is what the terminal and updater would be looking for.

In the terminal session in PyCharm I can't even get a python version for python to show up.
This code, `python --version` return the "No module named 'apt_pkg' error, however, running `python3 --version` tells me the version...Python 3.7.5

I have no idea how to rollback the changes I made or make the appropriate changes. Any help would be appreciated.

**Update**:
I've also been looking throughout my system to find where Python2 is (or where I think it should be). In /usr/bin/ there are the other versions of Python, but no 2.7. At this point I'm considering just saving my files to a thumbnail and reinstalling Ubuntu.

looking in /usr/bin/ this is what I see:

[image]

I ended up just saving the few files I had to thumbnail and installed a fresh Ubuntu OS (and went ahead and upgraded to 20.04). s an added benefit, as sound issue I was having has been resolved. I also installed Timeshift to allow to roll back any silly changes I make:)

Comment: Can you show us the output of terminal command `ls -l /usr/bin/python*`? it will be more definitive than relying on the icons in the file manager

Comment: I did exactly this a couple of days ago but I do not want a fresh install....any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to update your system from command line :
Open the terminal then type :

```
sudo apt update
```

You can try to upgrade your system from command line :
Open the terminal then type :

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

You will have an error probably, just copy past it here.

> best regards

Comment: Thanks, but still getting the 'No module named 'apt_pkg'. Look like the full return it too long for comment

Comment: Hello, can you try this solution ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13708180/python-dev-installation-error-importerror-no-module-named-apt-pkg/36232975#36232975

Comment: I can now run 'python --version and it gives me Python 2.7.17, but still cant do anything. I took a look at my /usr/bin/ to find it and the python 2.7 isn't registering as an application...weird?!

Comment: you can change it from update-alternative : https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-change-from-default-to-alternative-python-version-on-debian-linux